# Where can I find polemics between Reform and Orthodoxy?

Tags: product-recommendation, heterodox, orthodox, reform-judaism

I am looking for polemics between Reform and Orthodoxy.

Surprisingly, despite spending some time searching on Google, I didn't find anything online.

(Preferably not a book that I would have to buy in print, but rather online resources)

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/One-People-Two-Worlds-Orthodox/dp/0805211403  (You can get a used one for $3).

Comment: Have you tried replacing "reform" with _haskala_ and related?

Comment: The Collective Writings of Reb Shamshaon Refoel Hirsch also have some polemics. But of course they are only on one side.

Comment: Online? You'll just find people yelling at each other. Actually, yelling *to* their own camps, *about* the other camp. What are you trying to actually get out of this?

Comment: @Shalom I'm trying to find the underlying reasons why they disagree with each other's positions.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Yes.

Comment: @TzviK "polemics" is the Greek for war. If you want to actually understand the points of disagreement, look for something more like a dialogue. "Polemics" are just going to be what each side screamed about the other.

Comment: Anything that shows the history of the reform movement and the actions by the founders against other Jews is a polemic against this movement even without trying

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](https://a.co/d/f80qWlp) an amazing book on the topic:
One People, Two Worlds: A Reform Rabbi and an Orthodox Rabbi Explore the Issues That Divide Them

For a non-lechatchila answer.

Comment: Did you see my comment? :-)

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi oh sorry, I did not. I unintentionally plagarized. But it was worthy to be an answer anyhow :)

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4279/11501

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting sefer called אלה דברי הברית which talks about all the bans and halachos which came about due to the Reform movement . It includes letters from the Chasam Sofer ,Reb Akiva Eiger and more.

Picture of cover page:

[image]

Link to sefer om Hebrewbooks.org:

https://hebrewbooks.org/44543

Comment: That should be 'אלה דברי הברית ' :)

Comment: Corrected, tx..